# JVM creation failed in gephi software

Tags: social-networking, gephi, graphml

I have an GraphML Graph File. It is a large file. When I try to open this file in Gephi software the error message appears 'jvm creation failed'. 
I already increased the size as 1400mb by editing its config file. but again that error message appears!!

how can I solved this problem?
or are there any software to open GraphML graph file?

Comment: Same problem here.   Needed to backpedal to 512 and although it will stark, gephi now so unstable it won't work.   Going back to R!

Answer (score 1):

JVM creation failed is due to "too much of memory" (https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Troubleshooting). I experience the same thing, having 4gb on my computer don't know why I can't have 1400 for gephi. For me 900 is the maximum that can work.
I am trying SNAP at the moment, not sure if this works for you.